# XML data to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have looked online for transforming XML data to table using T-SQL. I only see part of the answer. My XML is a little different. Can someone help me with the following.

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML

SELECT @XmlData = '<header>
  <data>
    <numbersData>
      <numbers>
        <number>1</number>
        <number>2</number>
      </numbers>
    </numbersData>
  </data>
  <data>
    <numbersData>
      <numbers>
        <number>3</number>
        <number>4</number>
      </numbers>
    </numbersData>
  </data>
</header>'
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    Numbers.Data.value('(number)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Num
FROM
    @XmlData.nodes('/header/data/numbersData/numbers') Numbers(Data)
```

The result of this:

```
Num
----
1
3
```

Notice, how it only returns 1 and 3. 2 and 4 are missing.

Unfortunately, this file is coming from client and they will not change the format. I am trying to get the following result

```
Num
---
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: It is of no importance out of which `<data>` node your numbers are taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting those values which are **clearly** numbers into `VARCHAR(100)`? Doesn't make any sense....

Anyway - try this `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
    Data.value('.', 'INT') AS Num
FROM
    @XmlData.nodes('/header/data/numbersData/numbers/number') Numbers(Data)
```

The XPath basically "drills down" all the way to the `<number>` XML elements, and thus gets a complete list of all those elements, and converts their value to `INT` - this outputs the desired four numbers.

Comment: Yes, they are numbers here in my example. But they are alphanumeric in some cases. The example was simplified so that it could be clear to everyone. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

If you really need nothing but the numbers you've got answers already.

The following answer will additionally let you know, from which `<data>` node the number was taken:

```
WITH theData AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS DataIndex
          ,d.query('.') DataNode
    FROM @XmlData.nodes('/header/data') A(d)
)
SELECT d.DataIndex
      ,n.value('text()[1]','int') AS TheNumber
FROM theData d
CROSS APPLY d.DataNode.nodes('data/numbersData/numbers/number') A(n);
```

The result

```
DataIndex   TheNumber
1           1
1           2
2           3
2           4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, order was not important